# How do I fix this two IPv4 addresses on one interface problem?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, networkmanager

I set up an older debian machine to work as a router between a cisco AP and our fiber ONT. It seems to work for all my devices now except for my Arch laptop. The router is running some `nftable` rules to route from one interface (internal ethernet connected to the AP) to the other (ethernet that goes our to the internet).

My problem is that after some amount of time (on the order of minutes or tens of minutes at most), the laptop will seem to lose routing(?). It still appears to be connected to the AP, and a `dhclient` request gets answered (presumably because it's broadcast). I also noticed that the problem machine has a few unexpected properties (it's been a while since I used these tools; I'm a little unsure what is abnormal but most of this is pretty sus).

It is getting two IP addresses on the same interface which I have never seen before (NOTE: I changed the MAC addresses for this post, but they look like normal HW addresses):

```
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 12:34:56:78:90:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.50.36/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
   valid_lft 333sec preferred_lft 333sec
inet 192.168.50.38/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::2411:8267:ea3c:21d3/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

A verbose `dhclient` request shows some errors:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.2-P1
Copyright 2004-2021 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
Listening on LPF/wlan0/12:34:56:78:90:ab
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/12:34:56:78:90:ab
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.50.39 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 192.168.50.39 from 192.168.50.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 192.168.50.39 -- renewal in 236 seconds.
```

The DHCP lease address seems to be changing every couple minutes.

`networkmanager` seems to be crashing when the errors happen.

I use a VPN to connect to work machines but haven't found a connection between the drops and VPN being on or off.

I can "share" the wifi connection using my phone as a hotspot which seems to work indefinitely but it's just a work around at this point.